# Files uploaded to graphql are resolved automatically, unless they are inside an object. Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

When I was uploading files to graphql, I noticed, that sometimes I get them as Promise, and sometimes I get resolved file instantly. 
After some testing I found out, that if I upload file as a direct Arg, it gets resolved automatically, however if it is nested inside an object, you get a Promise (but the file inside is already there) which you have to await before using.
To make it clear, I'll add a small code sample to illustrate:

```js
@InputType()
export class TestFileType {
  @Field(type => GraphQLUpload)
  file: IUpload;
}

interface IUpload {
  filename: string;
  mimetype: string;
  encoding: string;
  createReadStream: () => Stream;
}

  @Mutation(of => Boolean)
  async fileUploadTest(
    @Arg('file', () => GraphQLUpload) file: IUpload,
    @Arg('fileObj', type => TestFileType) fileObj: TestFileType,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('Test File: ', file);
    /* GIVES
    Test File:  {
      filename: 'test.png',
      mimetype: 'image/png',
      encoding: '7bit',
      createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
    }
    */

    console.log('Test OBJ file: ', fileObj.file);
    /* GIVES
    Test OBJ file:  Promise {
      {
        filename: 'test.png',
        mimetype: 'image/png',
        encoding: '7bit',
        createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream]
      }
    }
    */
    return true;
  }
```

I would expect to either receive resolved file or Promise in both cases. Should I report this to issue tracker or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> A GraphQL Upload scalar that can be used in a GraphQLSchema. It’s value in resolvers is a promise that resolves file upload details for processing and storage.

So you should report that you receive a non-promise value that is not "thenable".